# Numbers give unexpected result (decimals)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently working on a function that takes the sum of different values in a multidimensional array.
I have the following code:

```
  cidSum() {
    for(let arr in this._cid) {
      console.log(this._cid[arr][1]);
      this._cidSum += this._cid[arr][1];
      console.log(this._cidSum);
    }
  }
```

Initial values of this._cid and this._cidSum:

```
this._cidSum = 0;
this._cid = [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]];
```

The results of the console logs where the first line is always the amount to be summed and the next line the new value after taking the sum.

```
1.01
1.01
2.05
3.0599999999999996
3.1
6.16
4.25
10.41
90
100.41
55
155.41
20
175.41
60
235.41
100
335.40999999999997
```

My problem is with `3.0599999999999996` and `335.40999999999997`.

1) What is causing these numbers to deviate from one or two decimals as they are always summed by one or two decimals?

2) Is there an efficient way to solve this (currently I would use math.round).

Thank you for your help,
Tom

Comment: 1) floating point math, 2) yup, everything found under `Math`, and please don't use `for..in` for iterating over arrays, use `for..of`

Comment: Or just `for(var i=0;i<this.cid.length;i++)` ...